# How do I restrict the generated code to tables in a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, jooq, codegen

I am currently evaluating jooq. I am very new to it. I want to use jooq to access a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. When I generate the classes, the codegen tool goes and generates code for objects from all the databases on that server which is not what I want.

What settings do I use in the configuration file to restrict the tool to only one database? I checked the [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/) and is not so obvious. Well, for restricting tables I guess I could use the `<includes></includes>` and `<excludes></excludes>`.

Could I use the same tags to restrict the tool to objects only in certain databases by using fully qualified table names with three parts [database].[schema].[table]?

Some other comments:

- It would be nice if the tool allowed specifying inclusion/exclusion rules per object type i.e. table, view, procedures , functions etc.
- place classes for tables/views/procedures in separate packages, if possible, instead of lumping them all together.
- One of databases had a schema `<Domain>\<user name>` and the code generated was invalid. Just make sure `\` are generated to `\\` in strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answers for your current questions / comments:

> Could I use the same tags to restrict the tool to objects only in certain databases by using fully qualified table names with three parts [database].[schema].[table]?

Yes, the `<includes/>` and `<excludes/>` elements match both qualified and unqualified names, so you can for instance exclude `database.schema.table` (leave out the brackets).

> It would be nice if the tool allowed specifying inclusion/exclusion rules per object type i.e. table, view, procedures , functions etc.

Indeed, that's on the roadmap: [#5263](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5263)

> place classes for tables/views/procedures in separate packages, if possible, instead of lumping them all together.

You can override the current behaviour with a generator strategy:

- [Programmatic implementation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/) (more powerful)
- [Declarative implementation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/) (more simple)

> One of databases had a schema \ and the code generated was invalid. Just make sure \ are generated to \ in strings.

Yes, the `<includes/>` and `<excludes/>` elements (as many other elements in the code generator configuration) take Java regular expressions with all the associated semantics.

### A better solution to your actual problem:

In jOOQ 3.9, you can use the [catalog / schema mapping feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/schema-mapping/) in your code generator. There are different ways to configure it:

#### Only one input catalog (standard name for what SQL Server calls database)

This is the simplest configuration to get you started. It will generate everything inside of a single database:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <inputCatalog>database</inputCatalog>
      ...
```

You can further reduce the generated output to only a single schema inside that database as such:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <inputCatalog>database</inputCatalog>
      <inputSchema>schema</inputSchema>
      ...
```

#### Multiple input catalogs

In more sophisticated setups (or as your project grows), a more appropriate approach would be to list all catalogs and schemas explicitly:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <catalogs>

        <!-- This configuration generates everything inside of that catalog -->
        <catalog>
          <inputCatalog>database1</inputCatalog>
        </catalog>

        <!-- This configuration generates only some schemas inside of the catalog -->
        <catalog>
          <inputCatalog>database2</inputCatalog>
          <schemata>
            <schema>
              <inputSchema>schema1</inputSchema>
            </schema>
            <schema>
              <inputSchema>schema2</inputSchema>
            </schema>
          </schemata>
        </catalog>
      ...
```

#### Background:

By default, the jOOQ code generator always generates everything it can see. There are two ways to explicitly restrict this:

1. [The code generator's catalog / schema mapping feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/schema-mapping/)
2. [The standard `<includes/>` and `<excludes/>` regular expressions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/) (which apply to all objects)

With jOOQ 3.8, code generation support for multiple catalogs (in SQL Server: databases) was added, without adding support for restricting them through the catalog mapping feature. This was rectified in jOOQ 3.9, when catalog mapping was added ([#4794](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4794)).

Prior to [#4794](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4794), the only workaround was to use `<excludes/>` to exclude all content from the unwanted catalogs, which resulted in the jOOQ 3.8 code generator to produce only empty catalogs.

[See also this discussion on the jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/nWE8RZKak5E/Uz6Bjed2AgAJ)